# How to create a derived attribute in SQL (Oracle Application Express)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, derived-attribute

I am trying to create a derived attribute (Number of seasons derived from first season). I think I need to create a view, but I am not sure.

Below is my code:

```
Create Table Officials(
Fname varchar2(15) not null,
Lname varchar2(15) not null,
Sport_ID number(10,2),
First_Season number(10,2),
primary key (Lname),
foreign key (Sport_ID) references Sports(Sport_ID)
);

Create View Number_of_Seasons as
Select Fs.*, extract(year from (current_date-First_Season))  as Number_of_Seasons
From Officials;
```

I keep getting the error:

> invalid character

Answer (score 0):

Select **Fs.***, extract(year from (current_date-First_Season))
Probably it is not able to locate Fs.* in the table created. Be precise about which Column are you referring to.

if you are referring to First_Season, then mention it as how you entered the table.

Comment: I tried using other column names that are in the table, I still get the same error.

Comment: maybe try changing first_season as date, because current_date and first_season need to be of the same character.

Comment: What would be the date datatype format? Just First_Season date() ?

Answer (score 0):

You said you use Oracle Apex. I presume that you ran that code in its SQL Commands; did you? If so, note that - even though you can *enter* as many commands in there you want, you have to **select** statement you want to execute and then push the "Run" button (or <CTRL + Enter> on the keyboard).

I created

- `sports` table (because it is referenced by `officials`)
- `officials` table
- `number_of_seasons` view

  - it is unclear what you meant to say by `fs.*` as there's nothing like that in query you posted. It *looks like* a table **alias**. As the only table you're selecting from is `officials`, I used that table's alias. Everything works OK (as far as creating is concerned):

[image]

On the other hand, there are some other *problems*.

- last name is a primary key? What if two (or more) officials have the same last name? Primary key constraint doesn't allow duplicates.
- You chose kind of strange datatypes. What is `first_season` column supposed to contain? It is a number with up to two decimal places. Furthermore, it is then used in `create view` statement. You're subtracting number of **days** from `current_date` and get e.g.

  ```
  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

  Session altered.

  SQL> select current_date - 5.82 as number_of_seasons from dual;

  NUMBER_OF_SEASONS
  -------------------
  05.04.2023 11:38:49
  ```

  which doesn't seem *right* to me.
- the same goes for `sport_id`. A *decimal* ID? Possible, but I don't think I ever saw people using it.

Therefore, as far as code is OK itself, logic that stands behind it isn't (to me, at least).

Comment: I've typed your exact code in and I'm still getting the "invalid character" error. As far as the logical stuff, this is just a small example project so it's fine.

Comment: As you can see, code I ran works OK. Could you post a screenshot which shows what you did?